# What is the most effecient way of adding and removing pieces of file to not rewrite it fully?

Tags: c#, c++, c, file

For example, if I want to delete 10 bytes in the middle of file or add 10 bytes to the middle, are there anyway to do it without total file rewrite?

I'd like a solution that does this task the fastest.

I use C#, but the solution maybe be also in C or C++.

Comment: fast solution, as in you get a fast answer or that the solution has snappy performance?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this. You may wish to consider an alternate file format that doesns't require adding or removing bytes from the middle.

Comment: @Keith Payne - the solution which is able to repeat modifying of 1gb+ file fast enough.

Comment: In any of those languages

Comment: @Manu343726: The OP's issue is language independent.  File handling is an OS issue.

Comment: What is is exactly you want to do? Perhaps there is a better solution, like adding the bytes to the end and keeping some kind of index as to where in the file data can be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to copy the entire file, omitting or inserting the relevant bytes.  This is an OS constraint; because of the way files are laid out on disk, it simply isn't possible to support this type of operation (at least with simple file systems like those used by Unix or Windows).

Comment: For my information: **entire file** or from the point where insertion/deletion occurs?

Comment: @MM.: In theory, you can read the remainder of the file into memory, then write it back to disk with the correct modifications. In reality, you *rarely* want to do this though -- for example, a crash in the middle of this can leave the file in an unusable state.

Comment: @MM. As Jerry says, only from the point of insertion or deletion, if you don't mind corrupting the file from time to time.  The problem is that the bytes behind where you modify are at a physical location on the disk; most file systems don't have a means of saying that n bytes at position x should be ignored, or that at position x, you have to get n bytes from somewhere else, so the only solution is to shift the bytes after the position of the change, on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try something that uses [MapViewOfFile](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32MapViewOfFile.htm). There are probably C# bindings.

You can then treat the file like memory which should be fast.

Comment: This is similar to unix mmap. Which maps the file into your current address space. You can then modify the file as if it was memory so in-place edits should be possible.

Comment: This may help a little if the file fits into actual RAM *and* you have to do many edits before the cache hits the timeout for writing back to the HDD. In the end though, a 1 byte insert at the beginning of a 10GB file will still trigger a complete rewrite of said file.

Comment: That is then about how the OS manages the file. Data on disk is present in blocks and the OS will only load a few blocks of the file at a time. If you are just changing some data, there should be no need to touch the unaffected blocks.

Comment: Yes, but if you add/delete data instead of modifying it, you have to move everything across block boundaries!!

Comment: Well then you will have the same problems as if you were inserting data into a block of memory. The last bit will have to be copied

Comment: Everything will have to be copied. Imagine 4-byte blocks, and the following file on disk: `|abcd|efgh|ijkl|mnop|qr00|` where `0` doesn't belong to the file any more. You want to insert `1` at the beginning. New file: `|1abc|defg|hijk|lmno|pqr00|` Not a single byte can stay where it was before.

Comment: I see... But this is the worst case. If I add 10 bytes into the middle, the physical file would be rewritten from the middle or...?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do at same place  delete and add ==> modify/update

open file in r+ mode this will give you change to read and write both operation can perform.
then

move the file stream to  where you want to modify and add that many bytes there 
you need not to delete 10 bytes. need to write 10 bytes. this will overwrite ten bytes from the current location. nothing but delete old ten bytes and add new ten bytes.

if you want to delete and don't want to add any thing ,then copy to new file except that ten bytes.

if you just want to add , move the stream position to end , write ten bytes.

you need `fseek()`

Comment: OP wants to insert 10 bytes in the middle, not overwrite them. Also, he says that he's aware of the solution that involves copying everything but to-be-deleted bytes.

Comment: @us2012 delete 10 bytes in the middle of file or add 10 bytes to the middle , isn't sounds like modify or update?

Comment: Sorry, it's really add or delete, so total file should become 10 bytes more or less.

Comment: @Kosmos if you write 10 bytes at the end of file. your file size will become ten bytes more. if you write in the middle ,i.e if you overwrite existing bytes then , file size remains same. if you delete... oops, we can't remove file content.  instead of deleting you can add some ******** at that ten bytes and consider that as deleted from file. after many more deletions there are lot ***** in your file. just remove all ******* from your file periodically.

Comment: "overwrite data-to-be-deleted with ****" - what if the file is binary, and there are already ***s that mean different things? Also, this still doesn't provide efficient insertion.

Comment: Sadly, my file is files container, so all bytes are used and can't be reserved.